# JavaFX mp3 audio, mp4 audio, text Data superimposing

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I am developing an application that finds files in different folder locations and displays all the files in a table view. If a user clicks on a row then that file gets displayed on the right side of the program. Currently, it is kind of working for txt, mp3 files and mp4 files.

**DESCRIPTION:**
I have created two services, **FileSearchService** and **FilePreviewService**. The FileSearchService searches for files and add those in a static observableList. The FilePreviewService gets the selected row, checks if the file is of type txt or mp3 or other and uses a FileProcessor abstract class to process the selected item. If the item selected is of type txt, the child class of FileProcessor, TextProcessor comes into play and returns an AnchorPane with TextArea as a child attached to that AnchorPane. The textarea sets the text obtained from the selected item(row). Finally the anchorPane is returned to the main controller. The Main Controller then displays the item.

**Problem:**
If i click on a row that holds a mp4 (or mp3) file then the mp4 (or mp3) file plays fine and gets displayed on my anchorPane. While the mp4 (or mp3) is playing, if i click on a txt file then the data of that file gets displayed on anchorPane but the audio of mp4(or mp3) is still playing.

Below are two images which describes my problem.

**I clicked on a video file, video displays at the right side of my application.**

[image]

Now i click on a txt file, then the anchorPane shows textData but the video(rather audio) is still playing.

[image]

Now, if i click a mp3 file then both mp3 and mp4  audios superimpose.

**What I want**

I want only one item to get executed. If a mp3 file is being played and if i click on a mp4 video then the mp3 should stop and video should play.My application can handle multiple consecutive mp3 or mp4 or txt clicks. Clicking a mp4 file followed by a txt file click does not get handled.

**FilePreviewService.Java**

```
public class FilePreviewService extends Service<Void> {
    FileModel model;
    private FileProcesser fileProcesser;
    String fileExtension = "";


    public FileProcesser getFileProcesser() {
        return fileProcesser;
    }

    public FilePreviewService(FileModel model) {
        this.model = model;
        this.fileExtension = reverseFileName(getFileExtension(model));

    }

    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {
        return new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                System.out.println("FIlePreviewService, createTask() Thread = " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
               fileProcesser = FileUtility.getFileProcesserFromUtil(fileExtension);
               getFileProcesser().processFile(model.getFileLocation());
                return null;
            }


        };
    }
}
```

**AudioProcesser.Java**

```
public final class AudioProcesser extends FileProcesser{
    static AudioProcesser audioProcesser;
     Media media;
     MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;


    public static AudioProcesser getAudioProcesser() {
        if (audioProcesser == null)
            audioProcesser = new AudioProcesser();
        return audioProcesser;
    }

    @Override
    public void processFile(String fileLocation) throws Exception {
        switch (getAudioMediaStatus()) {
            case NOT_PLAYED:
                playMedia(fileLocation);
                break;
            case PLAYING:
                /* TIP:
                If mediaPlayer.stop is placed after the line
                *  media = new Media(new File(fileLocation).toURI().toString());
                    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
                    then multiple music play together when multiple different row gets selected,
                    one after another
                */
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                playMedia(fileLocation);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Audio in default case");
        }
    }

    private void playMedia(String fileLocation) {
        media = new Media(new File(fileLocation).toURI().toString());
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaPlayer.play();
        setAudioMediaStatus(PLAYING);
    }
}
```

**VideoProcesser.Java**

```
public class VideoProcesser extends FileProcesser {
    static VideoProcesser videoProcesser = null;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    Media media;
    MediaView mediaView;

    @Override
    public void processFile(String fileLocation) throws Exception {
        switch (getVideoMediaStatus()) {
            case NOT_PLAYED:
                playVideo(fileLocation);
                break;
            case PLAYING:
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                playVideo(fileLocation);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Audio in default case");
        }


//        pane.getChildren().add();
    }

    @Override
    public AnchorPane getPane(){
        return pane;
    }


    private void playVideo(String fileLocation) {
        System.out.println("VideoProcesser Thread = " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        media = new Media(new File(fileLocation).toURI().toString());
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
//        mediaPlayer.setAutoPlay(true);
        if(mediaView == null) {
            mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);
        }
        mediaView.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);
        mediaView.setPreserveRatio(true);
        mediaPlayer.play();
        mediaPlayer.setOnError(() -> System.out.println("Current error: "+mediaPlayer.getError()));
        setVideoMediaStatus(PLAYING);
        pane.getChildren().add(mediaView);
    }

    public static FileProcesser getVideoProcesser() {
        if(videoProcesser == null)
            videoProcesser = new VideoProcesser();
        return videoProcesser;
    }
}
```

**TextProcesser.Java**

```
public class TextProcesser extends FileProcesser {

    static TextProcesser textProcesser = null;

    public static FileProcesser getTextProcesser() {
        if(textProcesser == null)
            textProcesser = new TextProcesser();
        return textProcesser;
    }

    @Override
    public void processFile(String fileLocation) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileLocation);
        Scanner sc = null;

        //text file: 25.1_-_Marvel_Graph.txt, size 1.5MB
        System.out.println("Data reading started = " + new Date());
        if (inputStream != null) {
            StringBuilder txtData = new StringBuilder("");
            try {
                sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
                while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                    txtData.append(sc.nextLine());
                }
                // note that Scanner suppresses exceptions
                if (sc.ioException() != null) {
                    throw sc.ioException();
                }
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
                if (sc != null) {
                    sc.close();
                }
            }
            dataToDisplay = txtData.toString();
        }
        System.out.println("Data reading finished = " + new Date());

    }

    @Override
    public AnchorPane getPane(){
        TextArea txtArea = new TextArea();
        txtArea.setEditable(false);
        txtArea.setText((String) dataToDisplay);
        txtArea.setPrefHeight(778);
        txtArea.setWrapText(true);
        pane.getChildren().add(txtArea);
        return pane;
    }
}
```

**MainController.Java**

```
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        init();
        initFilePreviewExecutors();

        for (int i = 0; i < locationsToSearch.length; i++) {
            fileModel = new FileModel(locationsToSearch[i]);
            FileSearchService fileSearchService = new FileSearchService(fileModel);
            fileSearchService.setExecutor(fileSearchExecutor);
            fileSearchService.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
                fileSearchService.setFileSearchCompleted(true);
                searchFinished = true;
            });
            fileSearchService.start();

            CacheFileService cfs = new CacheFileService(locationsToSearch[i]);

        }
        try {
            stop();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("fileName"));
        sizeCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("fileSize"));
        locationCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("fileLocation"));

        recordsTableView.setItems(fileModel.getData());

        recordsTableView.setContextMenu(new ContextMenu(showRecordInfo));

        recordsTableView.setRowFactory(tv -> {
            TableRow<FileModel> row = new TableRow<>();
            row.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
                if(!row.isEmpty() && event.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY && event.getClickCount() == 1) {
                    FileModel fileModel = row.getItem();
                    filePreviewService = new FilePreviewService(fileModel);
                    filePreviewService.setExecutor(filePreviewExecutor);
                    filePreviewService.setOnSucceeded(event1 -> {
                        recordPreviewPane = filePreviewService.getFileProcesser().getPane();
                        if(recordPreviewPane == null) {
                            System.out.println("RECORDPREVIEWPANE IS NULL");
                        }
                        previewPane.setContent(recordPreviewPane);
                    });
                    filePreviewService.restart();

                } else if(!row.isEmpty() && event.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                    FileModel fileModel = row.getItem();
                        showRecordInfo.setOnAction( e -> {
                        Scene scene = defaultViewFactory.getRecordInfoScene(fileModel);
                        Stage stage = new Stage();
                        stage.setScene(scene);
                        stage.show();
                    });

                }
            });
            return row;});


    }
```

I hope i made my question clear. In case if you want to see other java file then below is a link to the project. 
[Github :](https://github.com/karanpant/SearchEverything/tree/master/src)

Edit: The way i am solving my problem is very inefficient. I added some more code in FilePreviewService. Ofcourse the below code needs to satisfy some more condition. It's just a very inefficient approach.

```
 getFileProcesser().processFile(model.getFileLocation());
                if(i > 0) {
                    oldFileProcesser = fileProcesserStack.pop();
                }
                if(fileProcesser != null) {
                    fileProcesserStack.push(fileProcesser);
                }

                //audio and video consecutive play fixing

                if(i > 0 && (oldFileProcesser instanceof AudioProcesser || oldFileProcesser instanceof VideoProcesser)
                        && !(fileProcesser instanceof AudioProcesser || fileProcesser instanceof VideoProcesser)) {
                    if(oldFileProcesser instanceof  AudioProcesser) {
                        AudioMediaStatus.setAudioMediaStatus(AudioMediaStatus.JUST_STOP); }
                    if(oldFileProcesser instanceof  VideoProcesser) {
                        VideoMediaStatus.setVideoMediaStatus(VideoMediaStatus.JUST_STOP);}
                    oldFileProcesser.processFile("");
                }
                i++;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to stop a .mp3 when a .mp4 is played, or vice-versa.

First the why of your problem. You are calling `AudioProcesser` when you start an .mp3, cool, great. So you start a new `MediaPlayer` through that class.
BUT, you do the same thing using the `VideoProcesser` class. So now you have two `MediaPlayer`s running at the same time and thats why the audio overlays.

The solution, have an instance variable and expose some new methods for other classes to call, namely a `stopMediaPlayer()` method.

Example below, with as little changes to your code as possible:

```
public final class AudioProcesser extends FileProcesser{
    //Always have one instance of the variable.
    static AudioProcesser audioProcesser = new AudioProcesser();
    private Media media;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    public static AudioProcesser getAudioProcesser() {
        return audioProcesser;
    }

    //Added an exposure to the underlying audioMediaStatus
    public void setAudioMediaStatus(AudioMediaStatus status){
        AudioMediaStatus.setAudioMediaStatus(status);
    }
    //Another exposure to the underlying audioMediaStatus
    public AudioMediaStatus getAudioMediaStatus(){
        return AudioMediaStatus.getAudioMediaStatus();
    }
    //Used only for this class
    private void setMediaPlayer(String fileLocation){
        Media media = new Media(new File(fileLocation).toURI().toString());
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
    }

    //Exposed a stop method.
    public void stopMedia(){
        if(mediaPlayer != null) {
            //Change this accordingly.
            setAudioMediaStatus(AudioMediaStatus.NOT_PLAYED);
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void processFile(String fileLocation) throws Exception {
        switch (getAudioMediaStatus()) {
            case NOT_PLAYED:
                playMedia(fileLocation);
                break;
            case PLAYING:
                /* TIP:
                If mediaPlayer.stop is placed after the line
                *  media = new Media(new File(fileLocation).toURI().toString());
                    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
                    then multiple music play together when multiple different row gets selected,
                    one after another
                */
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                playMedia(fileLocation);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Audio in default case");
        }
    }

    private void playMedia(String fileLocation) {

        VideoProcesser.getVideoProcesser().stopMedia();
        //Moved the previous statements to its own method.
        setMediaPlayer(fileLocation);
        mediaPlayer.play();
        setAudioMediaStatus(AudioMediaStatus.PLAYING);
    }
}
```

As you can see I've added a few items, namely some methods and I got rid of your static imports. The important things to note are the `stopMedia()` method and the first line in the `playMedia()` method.

The `stopMedia` method does exactly what it's name says. In the `playMedia` method, you can see that I've added `VideoProcesser.getVideoProcesser().stopMedia()` as the first line.

The `Audio/VideoProcesser` classes are almost identical so the added methods and minor tweaks will transfer over, I have tested this and it does work.

Since you also want to stop audio/video when you select a `txt` file, you will need to add the same call to video and audios `stopMedia` method in that class as well.

Comment: yeah, I understand that. Later on I will be adding more features to my VideoProcesser, like recording some portion of the video file. Even if I merge Audio and Video Processer together, the other problem remains and that while the audio is playing, if i then click on a text file, then the audio will keep on playing. 

The way i am solving this problem is very inefficient, i have updated the question. I am actually using a fileprocessor and putting it on a stack and checking if the previous fileprocessor was of type  AudioProcessor then call their respective processFile() method and stop it.

Comment: Ah I see. Well i attempted to go through your code and refactor it but it would take too many changes for my ideas. Maybe someone else will have an idea

Comment: Could you give me your idea?

Comment: Use instance variables and expose some methods to stop the media players. Not sure how that will work when you launch new threads though.

Comment: I slept on it, and I've got a solution.

Comment: Do you really have a solution?